# Reading 6 column text file and matching the each term in column 1, 3 and 5 and to get the associated term of column 1,3 and 5 in column 2,4 and 6

Tags: php

I am reading one .txt file which has 6 column for example

```
CRP     1424    EN113   30  CSF2    2376                                                    
CSF1    789     ENH1    30  CSF3    923                                                             
CSF1R   1240    ENH3    30  CSRP1   809                                                             
CSF2    2588    ENK13   30  CTLA4   516                                                             
CSF3    1096    ENK18   30  CXCR4   2235                                                                
CSRP1   977     ENK19   30  CYC     1338

EDN1    1056    FA12    53  EN113   1136                                                                
EFC1    830     FA49B   23  ENH1    1136                                                                
EFC2    830     FAS     102 ENH3    1136                                                                
EGF     7905    FBRS    228 ENK13   1136                                                                
EGFR    6105    FBW1B   39  ENK18   1138                                                                
EGR1    533     FBX8    228 ENK19   1137                                                                
ELAF    1741    FGF2    67  ENK21   1138                                                                
EN113   830     FINC    63  ENK24   1137
```

I want to check, in column 1, 3 and 5 that term is available in other column is not?
for example, EN113,
It should present in all the three column (1, 3 and 5), I want there associated value also present in column 2, 4 and 6.
My script is able to match the term in three column, but I am not able to get the associated value for the term in 2, 4 and 6.

I have some initial try script...check it

```
$fn = fopen("jagadeesh_test_set.txt","r");
$fo = fopen("3column_output.txt", "a");

$pollfields = array();
while($row = fgets($fn)) {
// exploding data based on the '\t' symbol. Fetching contents between the symbols and saving in $pieces
$pieces = explode("\t", $row);

if ($pieces[0] = $pieces[2] = $pieces[4])
{   
    fwrite ( $fo, "$pieces[0] \t $pieces[1] \t $pieces[2] \t $pieces[3] \t $pieces[4] \t $pieces[5] \n");
}
?>
```

any suggestion, will be appreciated.

Comment: *is available in other column is not?* I don't really understand nor do I see what you want to do

Comment: I want to check, column-1 i.e 'EDN1' wether it is present in other other column in 3 and 6th? if so, I want to get the associated value with coulm match.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://pastebin.com/4jvayPS3 (<- Just change the path to the file)

Comment: So where are we now with this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about what you're comparing and what you're doing after determining each comparison but watch out for single equals signs (assignment operator)...

```
//If you're comparing the the 1st, 3rd, and 5th rows, use '===' instead of '='
if ($pieces[0] === $pieces[2] && $pieces[0] === $pieces[4])
{
    fwrite ( $fo, "$pieces[0] \t $pieces[1] \t $pieces[2] \t $pieces[3] \t $pieces[4] \t $pieces[5] \n");
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error, if I use you suggestion

Comment: Oh sorry, it is showing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\XMLfileReading\excel_3colmnMatch_with_Value.php on line 20

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand what you're looking for, you want to check if pieces[0] is the same as pieces[2] AND the same as pieces[3], correct?

Comment: Yes, that was I was doing. But I am not getting associated value, which is store in $pieces[2], $pieces[4] and $pieces[5].